# Java апплет - сохранение файла на сервере из которого был вызван апплет

Tags: java, applet

Надеюсь что вопрос сфорулирован правильно. На данный момент разработал апплет который находит на сервере необходимые файлы, и создаёт электронную подпись выбранных документов (файл формата .EDOC), и когда файл сгенерирован его нужно сохранить там же на сервере (PHP), где и файлы которые были подписаны. Апплет подписан доверенным сертификатом. 
В Java библиотеках, которые отвечают за работу с EDOC, предусмотрен метод writeTo

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     edoc2.writeTo(outputStream);
```

Поскольку applet находится в web среде, я использую FileOutputStream и в качестве параметра для конструктора используется путь до директории на сервере где нужно сохранить файл. Но во время выполнения периодически появляется exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\guntis-1.test.softikom.lv\com\mod_faili\dav_v17\index.php\2ckeq5ltj2i01697798bc8vqcs0\183522\16.06.2015.03.29.35.edoc (The network name cannot be found)
```

Существует ли какое нибудь альтернативное решение для данной ситуации?

Comment: Апплет исполняется на клиенте и никакой связи с файловой системой сервера не имеет.

Comment: надо учесть, что хром полностью отказался от аплетов, как от дырки в безопасности

Answer (score 2):

Клиент не может просто так залезть на сервер и сохранить туда файл, просто потому что нет доступа. А давать доступ всему интернету к файлам на сервере - это огромная дыра в безопасности.

Вместо использования файлового потока, апплет должен [выполнить HTTP-запрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314300/how-to-simply-generate-post-http-request-from-java-to-do-the-file-upload), передав этот файл на сервер специальному обработчику, которые его примет и сохранит. Разумеется, этот обработчик вам также придется написать, но уже не на Java, а на PHP.